# How to change items' properties in RecyclerView when chosing a specified item programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to change the background colour of an item in a list in RecyclerView using `LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(mPosition)`. I have two buttons which increment or decrement the position number. So, on specifying an item (going to that position using scrollToPosition), I want to highlight it (changing background colour for instance) to indicate the specified one. The case is that we don't have to use touch to scroll up and down and selecting the items (something like using tab key on keyboard to jump between items in the recyclerview).
I've tried `OnFocusChanged` and assigning an xml instead of background to see the different behaviors like on `state_selected` or `state_focused` but none of them was correct. So, What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the background color after scrolling to this position?
Try this:

```
LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(mPosition)
View view = LinearLayoutManager.getItem(mPosition);
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: Does it really work in the MainActivity? I could not found 'getItem' attribute in  'LinearLayoutManager' or in its object that I initiated (maybe you mean 'getChildAt', which when I use, returns error "null object reference" on showing new item in the recyclerView list) . I want to change the background colour of 'LinearLayout' of the specified item in the recyclerView by pointing to it using 'scrollToPosition'.

Comment: @ALstckOvFl Can you try findViewByPosition(mPosition)?

Comment: Result is the same: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference". My list contains four items at the time, Trying to show item 5th rises the error.

Comment: Oh I see. I think getItem(pos) returns the displayed item at this position. How about getItem(0) or (1) after scrollToPosition?

Comment: Nope! Once the new item come into the list, the error comes up. Even I've tried to define the view global but the result was worse than before.

Comment: I've figured it out how to prevent invoke error on  a null object. It triggered because the item is not correctly loaded in to the queue. The solution is to use `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition)` before `view.findViewByPosition(mPosition)`.